# Can't find Ghost.js source file

Tags: javascript, ghost

Where is stored ghost.js sorce html file? 
I want to create website using ghost.js, but I can't even find a html source file.

Comment: @Jai — The code they said they couldn't find?

Answer (score 0):

Ghost is a CMS. It generates content from templates.

See [the template guide](http://themes.ghost.org/v1.0.0/) in [the documentation](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost).

You'll find them in [the *themes* directory](https://github.com/TryGhost/Casper/tree/0914d43a8627b52503117340d04bf03c2865137a) with `.hbs` file extensions along with a [README](https://github.com/TryGhost/Casper/blob/0914d43a8627b52503117340d04bf03c2865137a/README.md) that explains all this again.